# How many bulbs should be inspected for probability to exceed $1/2$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

In a lot of $50$ lightbulbs, there are $2$ bad bulbs. How many bulbs should be examined so that the probability of finding at least $1$ bad bulb is at least $1/2$?

My effort:

Suppose $n$, where $0 \leq n \leq 50$, bulbs are examined. Then the probability of finding no bad bulb is $$ \frac{ 48 \choose n }{ 50 \choose n}.$$ So the probability of finding at least $1$ bad bulb is $$ 1 - \frac{ 48 \choose n }{ 50 \choose n}.$$ Thus we must have $$ 1 - \frac{ 48 \choose n }{ 50 \choose n} \geq \frac{1}{2}.$$

Am I proceeding in a correct fashion? And if so, what would be our desired value of $n$?

Comment: Looks good to me. Just go on, express the binomial coefficients explicitly, and you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is correct. I suggest you now try to simplify it using $${r\choose k} = \frac{r!}{(r-k)!k!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$\frac{1}{2} \leq1 - \frac{ 48 \choose n }{ 50 \choose n} = 1 - \frac{\frac{48!}{n!(48-n)!}}{\frac{50!}{n!(50-n)!}} =1- \frac{(50-n)(49-n)}{50·49} = \frac{99n-n^2}{2450}\Rightarrow \\ 1225\leq 99n-n^2 \Rightarrow 0 \geq n^2-99n+1225$$

Can you continue?

Comment: LOL, let me edit that

Comment: Darth Geek, how to arrive at the correct value of $n$?

Comment: First solve the equality: you'll get to values for $n$ that satisfy the identity, $n_1$ and $n_2$. Then any value between both of them will satisfy the inequality. You want the smallest integer of those values (If you still have trouble with it, I'll edit the answer with a full one)